# Drawing sprites programatically for sprite kit with alpha channel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to prototype an app for sprite kit, and it would be advantageous to me to be able to draw the sprites I need programatically for now, and then make actual sprites later.  I've made a rough circle, and when I convert to a UIImage (or CGImage) using renderInContext, it shows up on the sprite view with a black background, ignoring the alpha channel, apparently.  If I add the UIImage to a regular view as a UIImageView, the alpha channel is rendered properly.  I was wondering what I'm doing wrong, or if theres' a workaround for this.

```
float rockSize = 100;

UIView* drawingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
drawingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

CALayer* circleLayer = [CALayer layer];
circleLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,rockSize,rockSize);
circleLayer.backgroundColor = [Utils getTiledColorFromColor:[UIColor purpleColor]].CGColor;
circleLayer.cornerRadius = rockSize/2.0;
circleLayer.masksToBounds = YES;

[drawingView.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(rockSize, rockSize), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0,0,rockSize,rockSize));
[drawingView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *layerImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

SKSpriteNode *rockNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImage:layerImage]];
CGPoint position = CGPointMake(200,100);
rockNode.position = position;

[self addChild:rockNode];
```

Comment: I haven't worked with sprite-kit but it looks like the sprite view has opaque property set to YES with no opaque background.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  If you add it as an answer, I'll mark it as as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such an affect when you see black view background frequently happens when the view has `opaque` property incorrectly set to `YES` without actually being opaque (usually this happens when the view is created programmatically, opaque = YES is default).

You can fix this for example by setting `opaque` to `NO`.